# Git Add . permission error windows

Tags: git

I need help with step by step solution to solving `git add .` permission errors:

```
error: open (AppData/local/comms/unistoreDB/USS.jtx) Permission denied
error: unable to index AppData/local/unistore/USS.jtx
fatal: adding file failed
```

There no tutorial that explicitly address this problem. What does one do if one get an error message that the `git add .` point?

Comment: Is the entire repo in AppData?  Or just trying to add this from outside the repo?  I wouldn't recommend storing a repo or any file from it in AppData or any other privileged system area.

Comment: Thanks for your response. USS.jtx is located in Users/Dav/Appdata/local/Comms/UnistoreDB/USS.jtx. I Other files are in Users/Dav/.git. The file were located authomatically during installation of GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is a permission issue: check if your account can read/write in `AppData/local/comms/unistoreDB`.
Check if opening a `CMD` as admin would help.

The other possibility is that you cannot access (read) `USS.jtx` because it is preempted by another process. Use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to confirm it: look for `USS.jtx`.

That being said, yes, any Git repo in `AppData` is not a common practice.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The USS.jtx file is located in User/Dav/AppData/Local/Comms/UnistoreDB/USS.jtx. Other files are in in User/Dav/.git

Comment: I have check all permission in windows and they are fine.

Comment: @DavidOgula did you check if there is a process using that file, as I describe in the answer? Also, as commented by LightCC, did you really intended to create a git repo in your User folder?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> `USS.jtx` is located in `Users/Dav/Appdata/local/Comms/UnistoreDB/USS.jtx`. Other files are in `Users/Dav/.git`. The file were located automatically during installation of GitHub.

This appears to be an issue with how your Git repository was created, or maybe a misunderstanding of Git or Github overall.  Github.com itself doesn't actually install anything on a local PC, but Github does have a "Github Desktop" application, which is what I'm assuming you mention here by saying that "Github was installed".

Assuming your mention refers to Github Desktop, that app doesn't actually create a repo on your PC, it only connects you to Github, and allows you to either clone a repo from Github to your PC, using its GUI, rather than command-line git commands, and similarly allows you to create a new repo on your local PC.  Its default for new repos on my PC was `/users/<my username>/Documents/Github`

Since you have a `/users/Dav/.git` folder, it appears that you have created a new Git repo in `/users/Dav`, or cloned a repo from Github into that folder. 
 This is a bad place for a repository generally, because of all the special folders and files there, including the hidden system/app directory `AppData`, which includes the `USS.jtx` file you are trying to add to the repo.

---

If there is a special reason you need to store a copy of the `USS.jtx` file, my recommendation would be to create a repo in a normal folder location (like inside the default `Github` folder listed above), and either manually copy it into your repo when needed, or create a script that can ease or automate that process.  If there is a special use case as to why you need the repo in your home user folder and why you need to add protected files to the repo, the question would need some more information added to clarify that to give better direction.  If your repo is tracking an app that is placing the file into the `AppData` folder, then there are more standard ways of handling this use case of tracking the file outside of `AppData` that could be explained.

Comment: Your detailed explanation is much appreciated. This is the message I got from my latest attempt. Error: open (AppDat/Local/Microsoft/Office/Otele/{271520EF-AF70_AF70_4340-8301-F0AE95C970E8} – 6880 – Otele.dat”): No such file or directory
Error: unable to index file AppDat/Local/Microsoft/Offfice/OTele/271520EF-AF70_AF70_4340-8301-F0AE95C970E8} – 6880 – Otele.dat 
Fatal: adding file failed

Comment: So, are you just using `git add .` in your user folder?  What is the reason?  You will continue to get failures like this, somewhat randomly.

Comment: Was trying to create a Twitter bot, following  a YouTube video, but could not get pass the "git add" command.